# SQL: Variables with Quotes ""

Tags: sql, join, data-manipulation

I have noticed that even though the variable names in my tables are without quotes (""), the following SQL command does not work:

```
select var_1 from my_table limit 100;

ERROR: ATTRIBUTE "VAR_1" NOT FOUND
```

But on the other hand, this SQL command does work:

```
select "var_1" from my_table limit 100;
```

Thus, I am assuming that for some reason, I now need to specify all variables with Quotes ("")

**Question:** I am trying to run the following query :

```
create table test as 
select a.*, b.* from (

select "var_1", "var_2", "var_3" from table_1)a

inner join (select "var_4", "var_5", "var_6"  from table_2)b

on (( "a.var3" =  "b.var_4"  or  "a.var2" =  "b.var_5") and ("a.var1" = "b.var6") )
```

But this returns the following error:

```
ERROR: Attribute "a.var3" not found
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? I tried to run the above code with/without "" around the join variables, but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know Netezza. But could it be that it matters how the column was declared in the creation of the table? `create table test("var_1" int)` versus `create table test(var_1 int)`

Comment: @ LukStorms : Thank you for your reply! I will look into this!

Answer (score 2):

`"a.var3"` is not how you quote a column name qualified by a table name. Each name is quoted independently, ie `"a"."var3"`.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I tried the following code: create table test as 
select a.*, b.* from (

select "var_1", "var_2", "var_3" from table_1)a

inner join (select "var_4", "var_5", "var_6"  from table_2)b

on (( "a"."var3" =  "b"."var_4"  or  "a"."var2" =  "b".var_5") and ("a"."var1" = "b"."var6") )

Comment: But this gave me the following error: relation does not exist database_name.schema_name.a